# Jenkins scripted pipeline with sh is not working for multi line script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyfcl.png)

```
node {

    stage('Stage 1') 
    {
        sh "echo ${WORKSPACE}"
    }

    stage('Stage 2') 
    {
        sh
        ''' 
        echo ${WORKSPACE}
        '''
    }

}
```

Just got simple scripted Pipeline, where it has stopped working executing multiple lines of shell commands wrapped under 'sh'. Snippet is as per picture attached.

Here is the error I get when I execute Stage 2. Could you let me know how to fix this?.

Tried running below in 'Script console', but no luck

```
import jenkins.model.*
jenkins = Jenkins.instance
```

Error running Jenkins stage 2 is per below.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sh for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:28)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:10)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiline **sh** block should also start from the same line:-

```
stage('Stage 2') 
    {
        sh ''' 
            echo ${WORKSPACE}
        '''
    }
```

Comment: Triple single-quotes won't do variables expansion as far as I remember.

Comment: @vinWin you can also surround the string with parentheses to hint the `sh` its boundaries

Comment: Many thanks, to align properly, have made it to use different line, with the suggestion, it's fixed now! , @user_9090

Comment: Actually it does @MaratC . Both of stage.s output similar thing per OP. With later one being multi liner to run set of shell script commands

Comment: Thanks @towel for the suggestion, will do!

Comment: @vinWin with single quoted strings variable expansion happens within the shell command, instead of Jenkins' groovy engine. It works as long as you strictly use environment variables, but once you start using local variables you'll have to switch to double quotes.